# How to calculate the percentage in different rows of one column?

Tags: r, aggregate, summary

I'm trying to calculate the value as a percentage of the occupation and year. As an example, using `df` below, the first row's percentage would be:

665 /(665+709) = 48.4

I was able to use aggregate to calculate the mean, but am stuck on how to calculate the percentages: `aggregate(x=df$value, by=list(df$occupation, df$year),FUN = mean)`

```
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(rep(2003, 8), rep(2005, 8)),
  sex = c(rep(0, 4), rep(1, 4)),
  occupation = rep(c(1:4), 4),
  value = c(665, 661, 695, 450, 709, 460, 1033, 346, 808, 959, 651, 468, 756, 832, 1140, 431)
)
```

Comment: Please take a look at these tips on how to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as this post on [creating a great example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Perhaps the following tips on [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be worth a read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for is:

```
aggregate(
  x = df$value,
  by = list(df$occupation, df$year),
  FUN = function(x) {
    round(x / sum(x) * 100, 1)
  }
)
```

Basically, the crux of the answer lies in the `FUN` argument; to calculate the percentage, you need a function telling R what to do when aggregating. Since R has a built-in mean function, you were able to supply `mean` to `FUN` when calculating the mean. The [functional programming chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html) of Hadley Wickham's Advanced R has a lot more detail on building named and anonymous functions.

That said, for data manipulation tasks like this, packages like `dplyr` really excel at making the task less complex and easier to read. You could use the aggregate answer above, but unless you have a reason to (e.g. building a package and you want to avoid dependencies), the additional package can make your code more readable and maintainable.

```
library(dplyr)
output <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(year, occupation) %>%
  mutate(percent = round(value / sum(value) * 100, 1))
```

The other benefit to this approach is that it adds to your original data structure in a
cleaner way than the aggregate, which produces usable but not pretty results by default.

This [vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) has a bunch of great examples of these types of data manipulation tasks. The [dplyr/tidyr cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) is also helpful for these kinds of tasks.

My answer relies dplyr because it is my go to tool; there are definitely others (`plyr`, `data.table`) which may be better suited to a given task. I still like dplyr for this problem, but I mention other options because it is always worth thinking about [the best tool for the job](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail).

Comment: Thank you very much! You are so so so nice! I'm a new learner for R, your  answer is very beneficial to me!